Is it possible to have a Maven version-range with a common suffix?
Microsoft's mssql-jdbc artifacts are available compiled in multiple flavors: jre11, jre8 (and, probably, others). We currently use the following dependency-entry for it:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.6.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>

Now, we don't really care, whether it is 12.6.1 or 12.6.7, but we do care, that it not be jre19 -- as we're still using JDK11 in production.
Unfortunately, a version-range like [12.6.1,12.99].jre11 does not work. Is there some other way to express the same idea to Maven?

What about [12.6.1.jre11,12.99.jre11]? And why even using version ranges?

With range expressed this way, 12.91.1.jre17 will "win" over 12.91.1.jre11 :(
